# How to access the ID of dropdownlist in EditItemTemplate using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to access the id of dropdownlist which is in EditItemTemplate of GridView. I have access the id in FooterRow by using

```
 var ddlpresentday = document.getElementById("<%=((DropDownList)gridEarning.FooterRow.
FindControl("ddlFPresentDay")).ClientID%>");
```

but facing problem when GridView is in Edit Mode. 
Kindly help me.

**GridView:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridEarning" runat="server">
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Present Days to be considerd on" 
    SortExpression="TAXABLE" meta:resourcekey="TemplateField19Resource">
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditPresentDay" CssClass="ddlEditPresentDay" 
        runat="server" Enabled="false" Height="20px" Width="110px"      
        meta:resourcekey="ddlPresentDayResource2">
          <asp:ListItem Value="0" meta:resourcekey="ddlPreDaysListItemResource1">All Days</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="1" meta:resourcekey="ddlPreDaysListItemResource2">Business Days</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="2" meta:resourcekey="ddlPreDaysListItemResource3">Off Days and Holidays</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFPresentDay" runat="server" Height="20px" Enabled="false" Width="110px" meta:resourcekey="ddlPresentDayResource2">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" meta:resourcekey="ddlPreDaysListItemResource1">All Days</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" meta:resourcekey="ddlPreDaysListItemResource2">Business Days</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" meta:resourcekey="ddlPreDaysListItemResource3">Off Days and Holidays</asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblPresentDays" runat="server" Text="Helllo"
        meta:resourcekey="lblPresentDaysResource1"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</GridView>
```

Comment: Maybe add the markup of the Gridview to easily replicate your scenario.

Comment: add your gridview markup

Comment: I have added the markup of Gridview kindly review it.

Comment: @user3631063  Why do you want to use javascript for finding the Id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is huge help in such cases (specifically css class selector). Anyway even without jquery you can define custom wrapper element with unique id and rely on that element instead - like:

```
<FooterTemplate>
  <span id="gridFooter">
    <asp:DropDownList ... ></asp:DropDownList>
  </span>
</FooterTemplate>
```

And then you can select it simply like:

```
var ddlpresentday = document.getElementById("gridFooter").firstElementChild;
```

**EDIT**

Adding jQuery solution as well:

```
<FooterTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList CssClass="unique-footer-select" ... ></asp:DropDownList>
</FooterTemplate>  

var ddlpresentday = $(".unique-footer-select");
```

Comment: Thanks once again. :)